# Problemas com entrada e saída na linguagem C no Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, scanf

Abaixo tenho um código 
simples em C, o problema é que se eu deixar como está ele não imprime o nome recebido na tela, porém quando eu troco o `scanf_s` pelo `scanf` ele funciona normalmente.
Qual seria o motivo ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char nome[20];
int  ru;

printf("Nome: ");
scanf_s("%s", nome);
printf("\n\n");
printf("%s", nome);

}
```

Comment: San, esta resposta te ajudaria?(em inglês) [Header for scanf_s function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836661/header-for-scanf-s-function)

Comment: Me ajudou demais!! Obrigada de verdade!!